# ¿ Por que no recibo la información en mi servidor usando fetch()?

Tags: php, javascript, fetch

Estoy aprendiendo a crear API REST pero me topo con un problema cuando intento extraer información utilizando el `fetch()` desde javascript todo funciona de maravilla la información me la entrega sin problema pero cuando intento utilizar el ejemplo que otorgan en `https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch` para enviar información, el servidor detecta que se esta haciendo una consulta del tipo `POST` sin embargo al tratar de recuperar dicha información me tira error y si intento retornar el `$_POST` me arroja un string vácio del lado del cliente.

mi código del lado del cliente es el siguiente:

```js
var url = 'http://localhost/php-rest/API/get_products/';
var data = {username: 'example'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```

Nota 1: El nombre de la funcion es get_products ya que es la misma con la que hice la prueba de `GET`.

Nota 2: Para comprobar que el error no lo tenía yo, copie y pegue el del ejemplo que otorgan en la página de mozilla.

y mi servidor esta de la siguiente manera:

```html
public function get_products(){
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        echo json_encode($_POST);
        exit();
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404");
    }
}
```

y la respuesta que me arroja al hacer la consult aes la siguiente :
`Success: Array []`

Me podrían decir que puede se el error por favor es la primera ves que intento esto ya que yo trabajaba con AJAX de jquery.

Comment: Pero, ¿cómo llamas a `get_products()`?

Comment: Estoy utilizando codeigniter y tengo el controlador llamado `API` dentro de el tengo la función `get_products()` cabe mencionar que si hago la misma consulta con el metodo ajax de jquery todo funciona de maravilla. Utilizando exactamente lo mismo obtengo el resultado esperado pero con fetch obtengo un array vacio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun la documentacion de PHP sobre $_POST

https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php

> Un array asociativo de variables pasadas al script actual a través del
> método POST de HTTP **cuando se emplea application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
> o **multipart/form-data** como Content-Type de HTTP en la petición.

Al utilizar un mime-type distinto a estos (como `application/json`) la variable `$_POST` deja de funcionar. La manera de obtener los datos en este caso es con `php://input` (el contenido de la data POST en bruto)

```
$POSTDATA=json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso funciona cambiando el modo de lectura del `$_POST` en PHP. No sé exactamente por qué, pero la API `fetch` parece tener algún problema con los datos cuando no son pasados en forma de URL encoded o con FormData.

Inspeccionando la respuesta del código se podía ver que los datos no estaban a primera mano, sino que en mi caso (Safari) había una pestaña que ponía *Solicitar datos* y allí sí los encontraba. Además el parámetro `usingBody` de la petición aparecía en `false`. Lo que intuyo es que en estos casos la API mete los datos en el flujo de PHP directamente (`php://input`), de modo que hay que ir a buscarlos allí.

Si haces una lectura de este modo el código funciona, al menos en mi caso:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    $json=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo(json_encode($json));
    exit();
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404");
}
```

Ahí podrás ver en la consola:

```
[Log] Success: – {username: "example"} (prueba.php, line 110)
```