# Petición POST recibe respuesta con AJAX, pero no con Fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, fetch

Tengo una aplicación, con la cual necesito extraer una cierta cantidad de registros que genero con php y pintarlos en una página X a través de javascript.

El asunto es que, utilizando ajax, no tengo problemas enviando una petición post y recibiendo la respuesta, pero probando con fetch, no obtengo nada... Realicé una prueba de recepción de parámetros por post y esto sucedió:

archivo php

```
echo json_encode($_POST, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Usando Ajax, obtengo de vuelta `{"data":"data"}` sin problemas

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'datawidgets.php',
        type: "post",
        data: { "data" : "data" },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Pero usando fetch, solo obtengo un array vacío:

```
fetch('datawidgets.php', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ "data" : "data" }),
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { console.log(data); })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

No sé qué pueda estar haciendo mal o algún detalle que se me pueda pasar por alto, pero mi idea es poder usar fetch y desligarme un poco de lo que es jquery.

Comment: Cuando usas `fetch` con el método `POST`, [en algunos servidores no encontrarás los datos en la superglobal $_POST](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/382645/29967), ignoro el motivo de por qué ocurre eso. Entonces, puedes buscar los datos en el flujo de entrada de PHP, pues allí sin duda estarán los datos, porque ese flujo tiene los datos que hay en el `body`. Sería algo así: **`$post=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); echo(json_encode($post));`** Por último, te aconsejo que pongas un `header` con el content type y el charset también en PHP.

Comment: No tenia idea de ese detalle, lo voy a probar. De momento, creando objetos de tipo FormData, como muestran mas abajo, me sirvio de momento bastante bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo utilizo un objeto de tipo **FormData** para enviar los parámetros por POST, quedaría algo así:

```
const datos = new FormData();
datos.append('parametro_uno', 'valor_uno');
datos.append('parametro_dos', 'valor_dos');

fetch('ruta', { method: 'POST', body: datos }).then(res => {
   console.log(res.json());
   console.log(res.text());
});
```

Obviamente esto se puede mejorar mucho con funciones asíncronas que simplifican la lectura del código y su funcionamiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirvio esta forma para poder avanzar en el proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

El `fetch` debe enviar en `body` un **string** u **objeto**, estás enviando en formato JSON. Deberías quitar las comillas, el Content-Type es con mayúscula en ambos casos.. Quedaría algo así:

```
fetch("datawidgets.php", {
  method: 'POST'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), 
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log(response));
```

En JavaScript moderno, si envías un objeto cuya propiedad y valor son iguales, ej: **{data:data}** se puede pasar sencillamente así **{data}**.

---

También puedes probar agregando esto en tu PHP.

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($payload);
print_r($data);
```

Si eso funciona, debes retornar $data.

Espero resuelva tu inconveniente, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Probe como me indicas y sigue solo enviando un array vacio de vuelta, no entiendo el porque.

Comment: Que es lo que viaja en data, de donde viene?, que error te da en la consola cuando hace la llamada?

Comment: Inicialmente un objeto llamado departamento el cual almacena el valor de este `{departamento: 'Regiones'}`. Eso por defecto.

Comment: Lo ideal sería del lado de php verificar si estás realmente recibiendo data, hay que identificar donde se está generando el problema. Si lo recibes podrías compararlo con lo que recibes al usar Ajax, eso podrá dar una idea de lo que está sucediendo.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero como podria verificarlo?
Lo que me extraña es que de ajax no tenga problemas. 
Un detalle si... probe usando un pequeño formulario para ir cambiando el departamento y al utilizar un elemento de tipo FormData si envia y recibe bien la informacion desde el servidor, asi que quedo plop.

Comment: Agregué contenido a la respuesta, al final. Capaz te es útil. El problema puede estar en el tipo RAW de data, y sería necesario aplicar el php//input.