# Pasar datos desde JS a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, variables, post, datos

Estoy tratando de pasar los datos de las variables `selec` y `pagina` a PHP por método post pero las esta devolviendo NULL. Estoy sacando los datos de la variable sedes de un select y los de la variable pagina de dependiendo de que botón se presione. Los valores se devuelven como null por lo tanto en el php salta al else y queda el JSON como "bien"

JS:

```javascript
function verificardir(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var selec = sede.options[sede.selectedIndex].text;
  var pagina = "DIRECTORIO";

  verificar(selec, pagina);
}

function verificar(selec, pagina) {
  var datos = new FormData();

  datos.append("selec", selec);
  datos.append("pagina", pagina);

  console.log(datos);
  console.log(datos.get("selec"));
  console.log(datos.get("pagina"));

  fetch("../paginas/sedes/valSedes.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: datos,
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data === "vacio") {
        let alerta = document.querySelector("#alerta");
        alerta.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">SELECCIONE UNA SEDE</div>';
      } else {
        let alerta = document.querySelector("#alerta");
        alerta.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> CORRECTO </div>';    
      }
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include '../../config.php';

$sede = $_POST['selec'];
$pag = $_POST['pagina'];
$mensaje = "Redireccionando...";

echo $sede;

if ($sede === "Seleccione una sede"){
    echo json_encode("vacio");
} else {
    echo json_encode("bien");
}
?>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muéstranos el código PHP que usas para manejar los datos y responder de vuelta al cliente. Por otra parte, ¿confirmas que los `console.log` que tienes muestran los datos correctos?

Comment: En algunos casos, parece que PHP mete los datos pasados vía `FormData` en el flujo de entrada. Prueba de este modo: `$post=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);` Ahora `$post` deberá ser un array y podrás obtener los valores mediante: `$sede = $post['selec'];` y `$pag = $post['pagina'];`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/382645/29967) para más detalles.